# Async PUT Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm building a script to handle some data modifications via the Shopify API, through JS.

My strategy is pull ALL the orders from one date, and to run a function against each order, then PUT the new data up.

I've gotten pretty close, I have an array containing all the orders from a specific date. I am returning this data through promises.

I need help with the async nature of this function to work as expected. Currently, my PUT request is being ignored completely, and I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
(function main() {
  var yesterday = moment().add('-1', 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var scopeStart = 'created_at_min=' + yesterday + "%2000:00";
  var scopeEnd = '&created_at_max=' + today + '%2000:00';

  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var apiEndpoint = '/admin/orders/count.json?limit=250&status=any&' + scopeStart + scopeEnd;
    Shopify.get(apiEndpoint, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });

  promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log('promise data', data.count);

    if (data.count <= 250) {
      var secondPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var apiEndpoint = '/admin/orders.json?limit=250&status=any&' + scopeStart + scopeEnd;
        Shopify.get(apiEndpoint, function(err, data) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else resolve(data);
        });
      });

      secondPromise.then(function(data) {
        var array = data.orders;
        async.each(array, function(order, callback) {
          console.log(order.name, order.id);
          var thirdPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var fields = generateFields(order.id);
            console.log('fields', fields);
            console.log('----------------');
            Shopify.put('/admin/orders/' + order.id, fields, function(err, data) {
              if (err) reject(err);
              else resolve(data);
            })
          });

          thirdPromise.then(function(data) {
            console.log('Updated', data);
          });  
        });
      });
    }
  });
}());
```

My third promise never returns a console log. The put request does not seem to go through. Any suggestions?

Comment: i don't see where you're executing `callback` from async.each. The third promise also doesn't seem to be needed, nothing relies on it.

Comment: that said, i also see no reason the third promise shouldn't be resolving or rejecting. Have you tried catching an error on it? `thirdPromise.catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: I came to this conclusion as well. I suspect ```fields``` that I'm passing in might be breaking for SOME of the orders, which in turns causes the whole request to fail. Looks like it's not a code problem -- it's my first time trying to write nested promises like this.

Comment: His code should work however (though never call a second put without calling callback). I suspect generateFields() is throwing an error. From the promises site "By default, promises silence any unhandled rejections."

Comment: Yes, the promise does swallow errors, but it does allow you to handle them with .catch()